# Set Directory expiration in azure data lake storage using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-storage

I want to set the ExpirationDate for a directory which is stored in Azure.

I am using the code below which sets the expiration for files only.

```
Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemExpiry -Account $dataLakeStoreName -Path "/data/directory/" -Expiration $now.AddDays(30)
```

Could you please suggest how I can set the expiration for the directory?
It should set the expiration for entire directory and on date of expiration it should remove directory and sub-directory (if any present) along with the files

Answer (score 0):

The `Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemExpiry` cmdlet does not support folders, but you could do something like this:

```
Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName $dataLakeStoreName -Path "/data/directory/" | Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemExpiry -Expiration $now.AddDays(30)
```